# Why instance_exec and class_exec have this different behavier?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I found the following code execerpt from the documentation of `instance_exec`

```
  class KlassWithSecret
    def initialize
      @secret = 99
    end
  end
  k = KlassWithSecret.new
  k.instance_exec(5) {|x| @secret+x }   #=> 104
```

My understanding of why the instance_exec does is in the following diagram, it add the @secret + 5 in its singleton class

```
  +-----------------------+
  |   singleton class do  |
  |     def method1       |
  |     ...               |
  |     end               |
  |     ...               |
  |     @secret + 5       |
  |   end                 |
  |                       |
  |                       |
  +-----------+-----------+
              |
    +---------+-------+
    |  instance k     |
    |   @secret       |
    |                 |
    +-----------------+
```

So I came up with the code using class_exec to get the same result

```
k.singleton_class.class_exec(5) {|x| @secret + x}
```

It give me a @secret is nil error, I want to know why it is and what's wrong with my understanding

update:

I've noticed that k.instance_exec {binding} and k.singleton_class.class_exec {binding} have the different binding object, so they must be differnet. I still want to know how they works under the hood

Answer (score 1):

`instance_exec` is written in C and the c-api allows you to specify what the value of self is when executing a method.

Before it made it into ruby proper people implemented it by defining a method on the singleton class and calling that, not by just executing stuff in the context of the singleton class (you can see this in activesupport 2.x or as rspec_core's `instance_eval_with_args`)

The singleton class of an object is an object in its own right and so has its own set of instance variables that aren't shared with the corresponding object